# Combine column B data for identical Column A values - Excel

Tags: excel

I am working in Excel with the following data structure:

```
A   1
    2
B   2
C   2
    3
    4
D   3
    4
```

And would like to change it to:

```
A   1,2
B   2
C   2,3,4
D   3,4
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub reorg()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value & "," & Cells(i, 2).Value
            Cells(i, i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]